# How do I print the frequency of each word in the given input string using two vectors?

Tags: c++, string, vector

Here is my approach where I have tried to split the string into words and then move forward but this is not working.
For instance, the input is: hey hi Mark hi mark
Then the output should be:
hey-1
hi-2
Mark-1
hi-2
mark-1

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    vector<vector<string> > strs;
    string str;
    cout<<"Enter your strings"<<endl;
    getline(cin, str);
    int len=str.length();
    int j=0;
    string s="";
    for(int i=0; i<len; i++){
      s+=str[i];
      if(str[i+1]==' ' || i+1==len){
        strs[0][j]=s;
        s="";
        j++;
        i++;
      }
    }
    strs[0][j]="NULL";
    int freq;
    vector<int> frequency;
    for(int n=0; strs[0][n]!="NULL" ;n++){
      freq=1;
      for(int m=0; strs[0][m]!="NULL"; m++){
        if(strs[0][n]==strs[0][m]){
          freq++;
        }
        frequency.push_back(freq);
      }
    }
    for(int x=0; strs[0][x]!="NULL"; x++){
      cout<<strs[0][x]<<" - "<<frequency[x]<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The classic method is to use an `std::unordered_map<std::string, uint> histogram;` and increment it with `histogram["word"]++;` for each occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you have tried to access string elements via its index, which sometimes raises segmentation fault. To solve your problem, I came up with below mention solution.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

/* getWordFrequency : function with return type std::map<std::string, int>
   Param1: Input string 
   Param2: Default delimiter as " "(void space).
*/ 
std::map<std::string, int> getWordFrequency(const char *input_string, char c = ' ')
{
    // Container to store output result
    std::map<std::string, int> result;

    // Iteration loop
    do{
        // Iteration pointer to iterate Character by Character 
        const char *begin = input_string;
        // Continue loop until delimeter or pointer to self detects
        while(*input_string != c && *input_string){
            // Jump to next character
            input_string++;
            }
            // Iterator for output result container
            std::map<std::string, int>::iterator finder = result.find(std::string(begin, input_string));
            // Find element using iterator
            if(finder != result.end()){
                // Element already present in resultunt map then increment frequency by one
                finder->second += 1;
            } else {
                // If no element found then insert new word with frequency 1
                result.insert(std::pair<std::string, int>(std::string(begin, input_string),1));
            }
    } while (0 != *input_string++); // Continue till end of string
    return result;
}

int main() 
{
    // Your string
    std::string input_string = "hey hi Mark hi mark";
    // Container to catch result
    std::map<std::string, int> frequency = getWordFrequency(input_string.c_str());
    // Printing frequency of each word present in string
    for (auto element : frequency){
        std::cout << element.first << "-" << element.second << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I thought of this approach but the issue remains that I was bound to use vector to solve this. Using stringstream to get the input in vector can help resolve my issue I guess.

Answer (score 0):

So, I think your approach using 2 `std::vectors` is unfortunately wrong. You do not fully understand the difference between `char` and `std::string`.

You need to learn abaout that.

There is a more or less standard approach for counting something in a container, like a string or in general.

We can use an associative container like a `std::map` or a `std::unordered_map`. And here we associate a "key", in this case the "word" to count, with a value, in this case the count of the specific word.

And luckily the maps have a very nice index operator[]. This will look for the given key and, if found, return a reference to the value. If not found, then it will create a new entry with the key and return a reference to the new entry. So, in both cases, we will get a reference to the value used for counting. And then we can simply write:

```
std::map<std::string, int> counter{};
counter[word]++;
```

And that's it. More is not necessary. Please see:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <unordered_map>

int main() {
    // Our test String
    std::string text{"hey hi Mark hi mark"};
    
    // Here, we will store the result of the counting
    std::unordered_map<std::string, unsigned int> counter;
    
    // Now count all words. This one line does all the counting
    for (std::istringstream iss{text}; iss >> text; counter[text]++);
    
    // Show result to user
    for (const auto& [word, count] : counter) std::cout << word << '-' << count << ' ';
}
```

It seems also that splitting a string is some how difficult for you. Also here are many many ppossible solutions available.

One of the more sophisticated and more advanced solution is to use the `std::sregex_token_iterator`. With that you can easily iterate over patterns (described by a `std::regex`) in a string.

The final code will look nearly the same, but the result will be better, since for example punctuation can be excluded.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <regex>
#include <iterator>

using Iter = std::sregex_token_iterator;
const std::regex re{R"(\w+)"};

int main() {
    // Our test String
    std::string text{"hey hi Mark, hi mark."};
    
    // Here, we will store the result of the counting
    std::unordered_map<std::string, unsigned int> counter;
    
    // Now count all words. This one line does all the counting
    for (Iter word(text.begin(), text.end(), re); word != Iter(); counter[*word++]++);
    
    // Show result to user
    for (const auto& [word, count] : counter) std::cout << word << '-' << count << ' ';
    
}
```